# .htaccess redirect from non existing file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress installation and what I'm trying to do is the following:

http://domain.com/page.php to redirect to http://domain.com/page/ only if page.php does **NOT** exists. If it does, it should load page.php

I was thinking about something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

But sadly, it doesn't work. And also few more similar rules to this doesn't have any effect or return 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(?:html?|php)$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Worked :) Just two more things, how should I add .html f.e., so the same rule is applied if the URL ends with page.html? And can I somehow keep the second level. Example: domain.com/directory/page.php needs to go to domain.com/directory/page/ if page.php doesn't exists. I should probably edit my initial question but I'm not sure.

Comment: ok answer updated for `.html` as well and it will indeed redirect `/directory/page.php` to `/directory/page/`